# How to pass user id into django ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying ajaxify a like button that works fine without ajax. So I defined a static file:

```
$(function(){

$('#like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/news/like/",
               data: {
               'post_id': $(this).attr('name'), 
               'user': '{{request.user.id}}',
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
               },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert('You liked this')
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
                }
          }); 
    })

});
```

and modified the corresponding view as follows:

```
 @csrf_exempt
def like(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #lu = User.objects.get(id= request.user.id)
        puid = int(request.POST.get('puid', None))
        lu= User.objects.get(id= puid)
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id', None)
        try:
            liked_news = News.objects.get(id = post_id)
        except:
            liked_news = None  

        if NewsLike.objects.filter(liker=lu.id, news=post_id):

            liked_news.likes -=1
            liked_news.save()
            NewsLike.objects.filter(news=post_id, liker=lu.id).delete()
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(args),
                                mimetype='application/javascript')            
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("news.views.post_withslug", args=[liked_news.slug]))

        else:

            liked_news.likes +=1
            liked_news.save()
            messages.success(request, "You liked this news") 
            newliker = NewsLike(liker=lu.id, news=post_id)
            newliker.save()


    args.update(csrf(request))
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("news.views.post_withslug", args=[liked_news.slug]))
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(args),
                                    mimetype='application/javascript')
```

'@csrf_exempt' decorator is temporarily added to get rid of csrf errors.

However when I click the button I get from firefox

```
ValueError at /news/like/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{request.user.id}}'
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to pass in the current user from the Javascript anyway. The view already knows that information, because it's in the request. So you should just replace `lu` in your view code with `request.user`.

Comment: Nice tip. I removed the 'user' line from jquery data in static file  and the ajax get passed for the first time. However, the second time that I click the button, I get: TypeError at /news/like/
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f91d82bead0> is not JSON serializable. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Django template directives (like `{{request.user_id}}`) cannot work in *static* files. That's why they are *static* — because they do not change dynamically, and the browser gets the file exactly as it is stored on your server. The browser will receive the literal string `{{request.user_id}}` instead of the value of the `user_id` attribute of the request — because there is no Django request involved when serving a static file.

You will need to replace your static Javascript file with a template that you render from a Django view. The template rendering itself is the process that replaces template directives in template files with the values from the context.

Comment: I see. So how can I render the jquery snippet from views?

Comment: Exactly the same way you render any other template.